# What to do when missing requirements to use app

Tags: android

In my android app there are certain requirements required in order to use the app (Internet access, GPS, etc.). Now I haven't really found anything dealing with this so I don't know if its a mute point or not. A user can leave your app at any time and turn things off/on on the phone. If I am checking to ensure that data access is available as well GPS in the app oncreate and onresume and just tell the user they need to switch it on, would that probably be enough? I'm thinking not. I'm thinking of redirecting the user to a new layout telling them what is missing and what needs to be done in order to use the app. This layout would also include a button for them to continue once settings are turned on.  Is this a good idea or bad? I don't know if there is a better way of handling this or not so all input is appreciated. What do you do?

Comment: Add validation on the app launch and give the user options. Your question is too broad to provide a solid answer.

Comment: How is it to broad?

Comment: network connectivity can go down, GPS signal lost for **any** reason and this is pretty much normal scenario. If your code is not dealing with it then I'd say it's simply half-baked.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski absolutely. That is why I'm asking how others deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

You might find some of your answers in [Find Success on Google Play](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/guide.html). If a user performs an action without satisfying all of the requirements, you could present a dialog explaining to the user what the requirements are and why they are necessary. You might also provide a link to redirect the user to the proper settings.

**EDIT**: The best practices in this situation are probably similar to [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). [Permissions Best Practices](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/best-practices.html) suggests something similar to what you are proposing, which is to show some sort of message or tutorial explaining to the user what is required and why, and then redirecting the user to the appropriate settings.

**EDIT**: One more example: That Android Documentation shows you how to use the Settings API to check which settings are enabled, and present the Location Settings dialog for the user to update their settings with a single tap. See [Prompt the User to Change Location Settings](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html#prompt)

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out. First I've heard of it.

Comment: There were other best practices guides in the past. This is one of the newer ones

Comment: @ClumsyHamster, did you find the answer you were looking for?

Comment: @ClumsyHamster, did you find the answer you were looking for?

Comment: @ClumsyHamster, did you find the answer you were looking for?

Comment: It helped a bit but no real suggestions were ever given. Just ideas. So, it remains open ended.

Comment: I updated my answer. I believe this is more along the lines of what you are looking for.

Comment: Happy New Year @ClumsyHamster! Did you find the answer you were looking for?